# Different character encoding when I run spring boot fat jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encoding

### 1. Background

The result of `locale` in my CentOS

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

---

My ITerm character encoding is UTF-8 && The `.bashrc` file in my my local Mac machine have the following statement:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

---

### 2. Different character encoding

I have a spring boot fat jar in my CentoS.

When I run `nohup java -jar springboot-test-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar >> foo.log &` OR `nohup java -jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 springboot-test-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar >> bar.log &`, I got the same result for my log file.

```
file *.log

bar.log: ASCII text
foo.log: ASCII text
```

When my colleague login my CentOS machine using his Mac machine and running the above command, the log have the different character encoding.

```
file *.log

bar.log: UTF-8 Unicode text
foo.log: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

I want to have `UTF-8 Unicode text` character encoding, not `ASCII text`.

How do I do that? Thx.